# How to check if an Instagram connected to Facebook page is a professional account using API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api

We are creating ads that click to Instagram account connected to a page. But for this, an Instagram professional account is mandatory. How to determine if an Instagram account connected to a Facebook Page is a professional (business/creator) account using the Graph API? Any insights on relevant API fields or indicators for accurate identification would be appreciated.

Comment: Is connecting _other_ types even possible?

Comment: Hi CBroe, 
Thanks a lot for the insight! Just found that on connecting it will be asked to convert to a professional account.